# Backup local sqlite database in Adobe Air mobile projects to Cloud

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, air, flash-builder

I am having an application with local sqlite database in an Adobe Air application for Android and iOS.

I would like to give the user the ability to backup and restore the local database. Since on iOS you cannot just save a backup file on the file system/SD card, I am thinking of backing it up to dropbox or to some other place.

It would be great of someone could give me some pointers and code sniplets about the best practises for this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Dropbox Api](http://www.dropbox.com/developers) section. You can use it to save files exactly as you've described in android without too much difficulty. They provide some good resources.